# Time complexity difference in System.out.println()

Tags: java, algorithm

Why is `System.out.println("Hello World");` O(1) and `System.out.println(str);`  O(N)? Can somebody explain the difference?

Comment: Is it a homework?

Comment: Why is this downvoted so heavily? Can somebody explain?

Comment: Who told you that the first statement is O(1)?

Comment: This is a completely valid question. I don't understand the downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Hello World" is a constant so it is `O(1)` whereas string `str` is variable of length `n` so the complexity is `O(n)`

Comment: Complexity is a mathematical concept, it has nothing to do with sysout. By definition, constant are `O(1)` because they are not relevant to calculate the complexity. However, the size of your input are important. I advise you to read about Big O notation and complexity, it is a wide subject (https://www.interviewcake.com/article/java/big-o-notation-time-and-space-complexity)

Comment: This is wrong. Complexity has nothing to do with what input you use beyond determining whether it's the best, average, or worst case. Think about it: would it take longer to print a different constant? Of course it would. Therefore, the time isn't constant.